# Unable to run cholesky decomposition in shiny. Coerching issue from 'closure' type

Tags: r, shiny

I have a correlation matrix. I'm trying to run cholesky decomposition function `chol()` on that matrix and then transpose it by `t()` function and save it in a varaible.

The `correlation_matrix` elements are taken from the user and the values are:

```
    [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  1.0  0.8  0.2
[2,]  0.8  1.0  0.7
[3,]  0.2  0.7  1.0
```

I'm trying the following code in `server.R` to run cholesky decomposition function and transposing it and also below that is the code I'm using to display the output of `chsky_decomp`:

```
#Use Cholesky decomposition
  chsky_decomp <- eventReactive(input$corr_matrix_action, {
    data.frame(t(chol(correlation_matrix)))
  })

#Printing the entered correlation elements for the three varaibles 
  output$chesky_decomp_matrix <- renderDataTable({
    chsky_decomp()
  })
```

But I keep getting the error: `cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'any'`

Tried various formats in `eventReactive` such as matrix, list, and etc., but nothing worked. Where am I going wrong? How to run the two functions `chol()` & `t()` on my `correlation_matrix` and display it?

I'm very new to shiny. Please help!!

Comment: It sounds like your `correlation_matrix` is of type `closure` (meaning `correlation_matrix` is a `reactive()` Value). Can you check if you have something like `correlation_matrix <- reactive({ ... })` in your code? Then you'd have to call `correlation_matrix()` to get its value.

Comment: @K.Rohde -  SOLVED THE PROBLEM. Thanks a lot for the comment. Yes. In fact I do have an `eventReactive` code block for `correlation_matrix` because I was taking inputs of those 9 matrix elements from the user through input boxes over a action button click.